# Несколько html5-видео на одной странице. Реализация кликабельной полосы прогресса

Tags: javascript, html5, видео

Нужно вставить на одну страницу несколько видео со своим дизайном элементов управления.

HTML:

```html
<div class="video-holder">
  <video class="video" src="video.mp4"></video>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="play-button">
      <button id="play-pause"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="progressBar">
      <div class="timeBar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript для отображения прогресса воспроизведения работает для нескольких плееров:

```
const video = document.querySelectorAll('.video');
const progbar = document.querySelectorAll('.progressBar');

video.forEach(video => video.addEventListener('timeupdate', 
function(e) { 
   const videoWrap = e.currentTarget.closest('.video-holder'),
   video = videoWrap.querySelector('video');
   videoWrap.querySelector('.timeBar').style.width = 
   (video.currentTime / video.duration * 100)  + "%";
}));
```

Есть код кликабельного прогресса, который работает только для одного видео  на странице:

```js
var updatebar = function(x) {
  var progress = $('.progressBar');
  var maxduration = video.duration;
  var position = x - progress.offset().left;
  var percentage = 100 * position / progress.width();

  if (percentage > 100) {
    percentage = 100;
  }
  if (percentage < 0) {
    percentage = 0;
  }

  $('.timeBar').css('width', percentage + '%');
  video.currentTime = maxduration * percentage / 100;
};

var timeDrag = false;
$('.progressBar').mousedown(function(e) {
  timeDrag = true;
  updatebar(e.pageX);
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  if (timeDrag) {
    timeDrag = false;
    updatebar(e.pageX);
  }
});
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  if (timeDrag) {
    updatebar(e.pageX);
  }
});
```

Как переписать его так, чтобы отрабатывал с любым количеством видео?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, в функцию `updateBar` передавать не координату, а весь объект события. И на его основе выссчитывать текущий элемент для работы. Может так:

```
var updatebar = function(e) {
    var progress = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.video-container').find('.progressBar');
    var video = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.video-container').find('video').get(0);
    var maxduration = video.duration;
    var position = e.pageX - progress.offset().left;
    var percentage = 100 * position / progress.width();

    if(percentage > 100) {
        percentage = 100;
    }
    if(percentage < 0) {
        percentage = 0;
    }

    $(e.currentTarget).closest('.video-container').find('.timeBar').css('width', percentage+'%');
    video.currentTime = maxduration * percentage / 100;
};
```

В `updatebar(e);` передавать весь event.

На мой взгляд неправильно смешивать чистый js с js написанным на jQuery. Пишите в одном стиле, так меньше вероятность доспустить ошибку.

Comment: Да, я как раз воспользовался этим решением, спасибо! Все элементы управления работают для каждого видео в отдельности. Но хочу добавить кликабельность полосе прогресса воспроизведения (чтобы происходил переход в соответствующую точку видео).

Comment: Добавил немного кода в ответ

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую это вариант.

Comment: Немного уточнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но довести до ума этот вариант у меня не вышло. Не хватает пока знаний в javascript. Написал другой вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Заработал такой вариант:

```
const video = document.querySelectorAll('.video');
const progbar = document.querySelectorAll('.progressBar');

/* Отображение полосы прогресса воспроизведения */
video.forEach(video => video.addEventListener('timeupdate', 
function(e) {   
e.currentTarget.closest('.video- 
holder').querySelector('.timeBar').style.width = 
(e.currentTarget.currentTime / e.currentTarget.duration * 100) + "%";
}));
/* Отображение полосы прогресса воспроизведения */

/* Установка CurrentTime в точку клика  */
progbar.forEach(progbar => progbar.addEventListener('click', 
function(e) {
var x = e.offsetX==undefined?e.layerX:e.offsetX;
var getvideoholder = e.currentTarget.closest('.video-holder');
var wdth = getvideoholder.querySelector('.progressBar').offsetWidth;
var viddur = getvideoholder.querySelector('video').duration;
getvideoholder.querySelector('video').currentTime = x*viddur/wdth;
}));
/* Установка CurrentTime в точку клика  */
```

Comment: В целом не плохо, но можно немного улучшить.
Событие `timeupdate` у нас случается на `video`, поэтому получить его можем `e.currentTarget`.
А во втором обработчике стоит закэшировать в переменную `e.currentTarget.closest('.video- 
holder')`, чтобы не выполнять одинаковую 'медленную' нескольо раз

Comment: Подкорректировал, да, так гораздо чище.